# "info inhibitor" alerts - kube-prometheus-stack

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator, kube-prometheus-stack

I have alertmanagerconfig with below configuration and now I need to point info alerts to a null receiver, can I have multiple receiver and receivers?

```
metadata:
  name: Prometheus-alertmanager-config
  namespace: Prometheus
spec:
  route:
    receiver: alert-email-pagerduty-config
    groupBy: ['alertname', 'priority','severity']
    groupWait: 30s
    groupInterval: 5m
    repeatInterval: 15m
    continue: true
  receivers: 
  - name: alert-email-pagerduty-config
    emailConfigs:
    - to: {{.to_email}}
      sendResolved: true
      from: {{.from_email}}
      smarthost:  {{.smarthost}}
      authUsername: {{.mail_username}}
      authPassword:
        name: 'alert-smtp-password'
        key: 'password'
      requireTLS: true
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: Opaque
metadata:
  name: alert-smtp-password
  namespace: prometheus
stringData:
  password: {{.mail_password}}
```